# Why composer in laravel no install package in wsl 2 docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php

I'm trying install laravel package via composer in WSL 2 docker with `sail` laravel CLI, but composer not install package, why?

**Error screenshot**
[image]

**docker file**

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3.8'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_HOST: '${DB_HOST}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
    phpmyadmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin'
        container_name: pma
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: '${DB_HOST}'
            PMA_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8081:80
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

**information**

- windows version 10 build 19042
- debian wls 2
- docker 20.10.2, build 2291f61
- laravel 8
- composer integrated with laravel  2.0.8

how do I solve this?

Comment: the error for `chmod` implies your user (or the user running composer) does not have permission to create and/or modify files in the install directory.

Comment: thanks for answer mate. But is the root user that is executing this command, how is it that it does not have permissions?

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to check for proper permissions?

Comment: _"how is it that it does not have permissions?"_ Even root is not allowed to do it if the file system doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that. Deleted folder vendor, and run composer install, that worked.
thank so much childs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well, but when I fixed the file permissions, it was fixed.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/